# Redirecting with .htaccess (without the endless loop)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am basically wanting all visitors to a website to automatically be forwarded to a subdirectory called 'ter'

in my current .htaccess I have:

```
Redirect 301 / /ter/
```

That throws a 501 server error.. and another attempt ended up in an endless loop

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Should be

`Redirect 301 / http://your.hostname/ter/`

The 3rd argument should always be a full URL.

ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

**Edit**: redirect does not take variable, while Rewrite does. You must hardcode your hostname.

Comment: Hmmm. I have Redirect 301 / http://413Cr.it/ter but it still shows and endless loop in chrome..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort it with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /ter [R]
```